# Оформление репозитория

Tags: github

Можно ли подгрузить папку с ресурсами(*.png *.dll) в свой репозитории? Не считается это плохим тоном?

Я добавляю ресурсы один раз, а потом вписываю их в .gitignore, чтобы больше не отслеживать изменения файла.

Правильно ли я поступаю?

Comment: Вам этого никто не запретит, а правильно или нет, вам решать.

Comment: Ресурсы (например изображения) скорее всего фактически являются частью проекта, поэтому должны быть в репозитонии. dll - если это продукт сборки, то их не должно быть, если это внешние зависимости - то тут решать вам.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: `.gitignore` никак не влияет на файлы, которые уже добавлены в репозитарий. [Документация](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected;

Comment: Не знал, спасибо. А есть ли тогда какая-то альтернатива, или *.png так же должна постигнуть участь системы контроля версии.

Comment: Возможно стоит рассмотреть вариант добавления ресурсов в основной репозиторий отдельным сабмодулем, что тоже удобно